# how to urlencode a value that is a python dictionary with encoded unicode characters

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, urllib

I'm trying to make a url-encoded web request in python 2.7 where I want to send a list of python dictionaries that would be on the server decoded as a list of JSON objects.
In essence I'm making:

`>>>urllib.urlencode({"param":"val", "items":[item1, item2] }, True)`

where `item1` can be something like `{ "a": u"š".encode("utf8") }` (simplified for the example)

The problem arises because of the unicode characters.

If an `item1` is by itself encoded, you get something meaningful:

```
>>>urllib.urlencode(item1)
'a=%C5%A1'
```

however, if I call `urllib.urlencode({"test": item1})` I get a mess:

```
'test=%7B%27a%27%3A+%27%5Cxc5%5Cxa1%27%7D'
```

In this case, the unicode character is no longer encoded as `%C5%A1` but as a longer sequence that is then incorrectly decoded on the server side.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to properly transform complex dictionary values (i.e. `item1`) before calling `urlencode` to avoid this issue?

Comment: 1. What is the decoding outcome on the server side? 2. What would you expect as a result of `urllib.urlencode({"test": item1})`?

Comment: Yes, there is no standard way to encode a structured object like a `dict` into URL query parameters. As a last resort for want of anything better to do, Python has included a string representation of the object literal, a URL-encoded version of `{'a': '\\xc5\\xa1'}`, but if your server-side application accepts structured objects you'll need to know what custom format it wants for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by first calling json.dumps(item) for each item in item list and then calling urllib.urlencode.

In short:

```
>>>urllib.urlencode({"param":"val", "items":[json.dumps(item) for item in items] }, True)
```

This solved the problem because the unicode characters are then encode using the \uXXXX which can be on the server side properly decoded with a json parser.

Comment: json.dumps works in your case. But it is not a general solution for the general problem. I think this needs to be fixed in the python docs: http://bugs.python.org/issue26433

Answer (score 0):

One way or another you need to decode anything that was encoded before re-encoding Here is one approach:

```
dictionary = {"test": item1}
urllib.urlencode(dict([(k, decode_operation(v)) for k, v in dictionary.iteritems()]))
```

Comment: Actually unquote doesn't work here, you need what ever is the inverse operation of your encoding there.